# zbateson/mail-mime-parser Mime Stream failure

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to use the mail mime parser from zbateson (https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser). I run into this issue:

Uncaught TypeError: stream_get_meta_data(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Utils.php:305

The code is very simpel:

```
$connect = imap_open($host, $user, $password)
or die('unable to connect Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
            
$parser = new MailMimeParser();
$message = $parser->parse($connect , true);
```

I can use all imap_commands so the $connect is valid.

I am not sure if I can use the imap_stream that way, anybody can give me a hint here?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Part of the code has been taken from https://mail-mime-parser.org/ section "Parsing an email"

Comment: The examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) look nothing like what you have. I don't even see a `MailMimeParser` class anywhere.

Comment: I took this code from https://mail-mime-parser.org/ from the section Parsing an email

Comment: Well, that's not the same GitHub page as the one you refer to in the beginning of your question. Anyway, [imap_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) return an imap resource or IMAP\Connection class, depending on your version of PHP. It is not a string, a streamable resource handle, or Psr7 StreamInterface stream. To get an email from an IMAP Connection you could use [this tutorial](https://www.techfry.com/php-tutorial/how-to-read-emails-using-php).